# Trying to host a custom font

Tags: github, fonts, hosting, google-fonts

So I know that this has been asked a few times before, but I'm struggling a bit since the previous methods are a bit outdated now from what I can tell.

So I am working on a website, and I want to be able to use a custom font for a few different projects. Problem is, the fonts need to be hosted on a server, as the site doesn't exactly have a way to host fonts files. So, I'm trying to be a bit creative and seeing if I can host it on github, or maybe another alternative similar to how Google Fonts work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, or just pointing me in the right direction as it has been a while since I've done anything like this.

Comment: It's your own custom font? A font with an open-source license you obtained somewhere? A font you have licensed from a vendor?

Comment: Open source font with permission from the creator